# Want to Display 3 months at a time in FullCalendar (adam Shaw)

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to be able to view 3 large months at a time using FullCalendar by Adam Shaw in my WP site.  Possible? In other words, current month, plus two more.  A 90 day events Calendar starting with the if the current date falls in a given month.  Example, today is July 26, so display July, Aug, Sept.

Any ideas?  I am calling it for use in a WP Events manager application.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Create three FullCalendar instances next to each other:

- Set the [defaultView](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/defaultView/) for all three to 'month'.
- Disable the previous and next buttons for two of the three calendar instances by manipulating their [headers](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/header/).
- Disable any other views (like agendaDay, agendaWeek, etc.) in all calendar [headers](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/header/).
- Whenever the [viewDisplay](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/viewDisplay/) callback is called on the calendar with the previous and next buttons, update the other calendar's date using [gotoDate](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/gotoDate/).

If you also need to use a week and/or day view, you may wish to set them up in a similar way, although I can imagine that would be confusing. You could also hide (using CSS) two of the three calendars when the user navigates to day or week view, and make them reappear when the user selects month view again. You probably need some CSS hocus pocus anyway to make it all look slick, but I think it should be doable.

Comment: Well actually thats a solution that will have later problems like passing the events from one calendar to another or event creation. But if the main objective is to show only events from a source, it will do. The thing is this is not a native view. Personally i have made a request to Adam's forum, a TRIMESTER view, but with no response what so ever...

Comment: Another problem would be that some dates would be displayed twice, as FullCalendar includes some dates from the next and previous months in month view. Why would event creation be problematic?

Comment: If you load the events yourself and pass them as an array, you could pass the same array to all 3 calendars, and the use css to keep those phantom dates from displaying at all.